# Model not animated even if animator fed correct data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

Short question! Have an Animator, thats being fed data. Debug.Loged it and it's getting the values correctly, even in realtime, while in game, the data is being passed. Got a riged guy, animations set in blend trees, all seems good, values calculated correctly... BUT... The model doesn't move. I can see the rig itself moving (on the picture in game view, those red debug joints are definitely moving as they should [as seen here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7iNb.jpg)) but the model doesn't follow, it's stays motionless in T a pose. Anyone please has an idea, where the problem might be? Im i missing something?
Seems like somewhere between the model and the Avatar. Thanks! (Im kinda losing my mind here....) Cheers!

Code (quite simple really):

```
//Start
animatorPlayer = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

//FixedUpdate
  AnimFeed(forward, turn, animGrounded, jumping, isCrouched);


//The feeding function
    void AnimFeed(float Forward, float Turn, bool animGrounded, bool jumping, bool isCrouched)
    {

        animatorPlayer.SetFloat("Forward", Forward);
        animatorPlayer.SetFloat("Turn", Turn);
        animatorPlayer.SetBool("OnGround", animGrounded);
        animatorPlayer.SetBool("Crouch", isCrouched);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I have no idea what that was, but when i switched the prefab... Tadah...Animator worked perfectly. So.. Problem solved, no idea how though, which iritates me... If anyone could still check it briefly out and try to explain, id be SUPER greatfull!
Cheers!